# False Error during migration: Date Modified earlier than Date Created

Tags: datetime, migration

When I try to insert some records, it throws back an Error report telling me that some of the records have a modified date before the created date. When I look at the corresponding field, this is not true and the modified date is indeed *after* the created date.

Why is this error being wrongly generated?

I'm using the Apex Data Loader.

Comment: Does the data you are loading include "Date Modified" and/or "Date Created"?

Comment: Yes, of course. All of them do. The error is being generated off the checks on those two fields for each record. Salesforce has already turned on Audit Fields for the sake of migration for my company so that dates can be moved over.

Comment: Is it possible that the error is actually on one of the other records in the batch - that is, the error is reported on row x (1 of 200) but actually exists on row y?

Comment: No, I've already pulled up a report of the situation from the old database and there is no record where the date created is after the date modified.

Comment: Have you checked the Date formats for dd:MM vs MM:dd mistakes? Check it against your organization date format

Comment: Also, if you're GMT-xx (east of GMT), the days loader needs the "use European dates" option turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Time Zone setting in the Apex Data Loader needed to be changed to GMT+00:00 since the time data is in GMT+00:00 format. It was set to GMT+04:00 and so was adding a four hours to the data I was migrating, making it seem like some of the recently created records were created in the future.

Comment: thanks for posting the answer; this is the kind of thing that would mess me up and leave me puzzled for some time